# What is this object on an MD-11?

Tags: aircraft-design, feature-identification, tail, md-11

There is something above the engine on the tail of this MD-11:
[image: md11]

What is that?

[Source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Varig/McDonnell-Douglas-MD-11/2775385/&sid=8ad2b3a626cf3bff1ea9938a6e757469)

Comment: They all have that,  it's part of the fairing. Are you asking what is purpose is,  or why it's on that particular aircraft?

Comment: That is the pylon that supports the engine. More details in  [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Aircraft-Design/What-is-the-aerodynamic-reason-for-making-the-lower-section-of-the-MD-11s-vertical-tail-so-big)

Comment: You should provide the source of your image, a direct link to the page containing the image and the author information. You forget nearly systematically to do it, and from a legal standpoint this is not possible (and in my opinion not ethical either). Here is [an example](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25651/was-this-a-successful-deployment-of-an-md-88-tail-cone-evacuation-slide).

Comment: Possible duplicate of:   https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51883/what-is-this-tab-above-the-dc-10s-2-engine

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As was said in the comments above, it is the support structure for the engine as seen in this drawing:

[image]

[image]