# What is this tab above the DC-10's #2 engine?

Tags: jet-engine, feature-identification, tail, dc-10

What is this big rectangular tab (?) thingy extending backwards just above the DC-10's #2 engine? What does it do?

[image: photo]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:McDonnell_Douglas_DC-10-30,_Korean_Air_AN0199462.jpg), picture modified to point out the tab thingy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]
([airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=776385#p11200257) via [szextant.blogspot.com](https://szextant.blogspot.com/2014/01/jet-engines-turbofans-turboshaft-detail.html))

It mostly houses the same stuff that's on an underwing engine pylon: bleed air ducts, wiring, fuel and hydraulic hoses and tubes that connect to the engine core and accessories. The aft part of the structure where it tapers is just there out of aerodynamic necessity.

Answer (score 2):

Also the stuff at the end of the fuselage below the engine is just a fairing. It will fold away and the engine is removed by installing a bracket on the pylon and using cables to lower the engine straight down. If it was deeper in the fin as Sean mentioned, it would need to be drawn backwards and then down, making it more complex to do an engine swap.

Answer (score 1):

[DC10](https://www.norebbo.com/2012/06/mcdonnell-douglas-dc-10-30-blank-templates/) rear engine pylon, same as underwing, for supporting the engine. The tube that looks like it could provide support is just a very long intake duct. [image]

Comment: So why not put the engine further forward in that tube, which would allow the engine to be supported by the horizontal stabilizer directly and allow its ancillaries to be placed within the stabilizer itself rather than needing an external pylon?

Comment: @Sean - The long inlet is to straighten out the air after the fuselage disturbance, especially at high angles of attack.

Comment: @sean You don't want an engine explosion to blow all the control surfaces off the aircraft. UA232's #2 engine failure took out all three hydraulic systems and control of the tail, but were able to land. If the engine had been mounted farther forward they might have lost the control surfaces altogether and consequently the plane.

Comment: @Pilothead: Good point, although it wouldn't matter nowadays (since all jet engines are now required to contain any and all debris within the engine under any and all possible failure scenarios).

Comment: @sean As they always have, and as well demonstrated by SWA1380, SWA3272 in 2016, QF032 in 2010, AF066 in 2017...

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought that was a more recent (post-UA232) requirement...

Comment: You might want to add the bit about explodey-engine protection into your answer.